# Why am i getting error: recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream during ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, nginx, server, fastcgi

I had problem with ajax. It always stopped working 5 min after request. I did't know what was causing it. I looked on many pages to find a sollution but nor provide good one. What I can do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check what you have set in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file in line request_terminate_timeout. I has got:

`request_terminate_timeout = 300s`

This is because it had always stopped working after 5 min (300s = 5min)

After i changed it to `request_terminate_timeout = 3600s` my problem have gone. I have got now 60 min to complete my ajax request :)

PS Make sure that you remove `;` before that line because it is used to comment line.